# Adding bootstrap classes with html helper methods not working?

Tags: c#, html, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there any way to add bootstrap classes like  form-control to asp.net mvc html helper methods like @html.Textbox("searchString");?

this is the code I have in the view

@*this is the html output for the search bar taking searchstring param from controller in htmlhelper*@

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>

                Search: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
                <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Search" />

            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

It seems like everything is playing nice with bootstrap except the @Html.Textbox and its messing up my UI.
is there a way to affect the @Html.Textbox with bootstrap form-control class?

ps the "SearchString" variable comes from my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You have the possibility to add HtmlAttributes:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And if you're using a property from your @model:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new {@class="form-control"});`

Answer (score 0):

[One variation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) of the `@Html.TextBox` helper takes an anonymous `object` that you can use to pass in HTML attributes. You would use it like:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I think you'll need an `@` before `class`, as class is a reserved word.